# Properly addressing programming questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

When I tend to answer a programming question, I try to give the OP something they can build on rather than a full blown class or function.

I definitely see a lot of people providing full blown implementations that the OP is probably just copying and pasting.

Of course I understand this is fully within the scope of the individual choosing to answer the question.

My question is, should we, as a community, be answering questions with full blown implementations for new users? Sure it's nice, but it seems the chances of new users really learning anything diminishes on full blown code they can hardly even decipher that they might be just copying and pasting.

To be clear based on comments: I do not encourage giving incomplete answers.

Comment: If I can be honest, I would still prefer to learn. I perfectly understand not everyone has that mentality however.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I believe I may have not been clear. Not incomplete answers precisely.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a repository of questions and answers. The right answer to a particular niche question is generally less useful than the illustration and explanation of how/what/why. But a worked example is generally a good supplement to an answer. I don't think a complete solution is ever necessary. Something that doesn't quite work might help someone learn, but would rather something that 'works' but needs extending than something that needs fixing before I can even try.

Comment: Very much IMHO, but I never just copy a code example and try to get it to compile.  Ever.  Not for reasons of paranoia or anything like that, but it almost always needs to be modified (at least slightly) to fit my application.  My own code examples tend to use "..." to signify "you must put relevant code here" for things like memory allocation, error checking, input and output processing, etc.  Stuff that I assume the OP knows how to do, and will need to do themselves anyway -- unless the question is specifically about how to do those things.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would make sense to make a general rule out of any answer to this question; there are too many variables involved. In any case, I generally agree with @Sobrique .

Comment: As a relative novice to C# .NET programming, I regularly use Stack Overflow as a reliable learning resource.  My favourite answers are those that provide a succinct example in the answer, and include a link to an off-site resource (GitHub, Code Project, a blog, etc.) where a complete implementation can be found.  They are rare gems.

Comment: I have zero stats on this but I have the impression that a number of questions look (to me) like requests for help with homework.  Id say such cases should NOT have complete solutions.   Otherwise, Id say theres no blanket answer, it depends.   The metaphor about fish and fishing rods springs to mind.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The nitty-gritty details of code implementation are important too, but you can't get those without a full example. (And, unfortunately, a lot of examples don't have enough details worked out; they show too clinical a view of code, without really giving a realistic view of the messiness needed to handle things properly.)

To avoid encouraging [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), I recommend giving explanations before the code that outline the approach, and perhaps comments within the code itself. Copy and paste is not the (main*) problem; lack of understanding is. Fighting that is therefore the main goal.

I have an [auto-comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) for non-trivial code-only answers, in fact, which goes like this:

> `Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272), because they don't teach the solution.`

(Unlike some, I do not consider code-only answers ripe for deletion in most cases. They are of *some* value, just not as much.)

<sub>**It is **a** problem, however, since C&P is a lot harder to version properly in synch, especially when you have years-old articles floating around the web.*</sub>

Comment: I like that autokey and the fact that you do that.

Comment: @pnuts: Right. I don't add the comment if it's basically just "call this method" or similar. I *do* add it if it's six lines of line noise with three characters in there different, though. ;)

Comment: I completely agree. Some of the most amazing answers I have seen were full implementations of very complex solutions to custom LINQ operations in C#. They had multiple classes and some words I barely understood. I did not use them because after reading them I knew I would never understand them well enough to maintain them. That being said, they did point me in the direction of what I did need to learn to eventually get there. A simple incomplete solution may have actually lead me down the rabbit hole instead of showing me I should steer clear of the danger.

Comment: For anyone else interested in what cargo cult programming is, go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). I had imagined it was a club of programmers that wore [cargo pants](https://www.google.nl/search?tbm=isch&q=cargo+pants) to work.

Comment: @mason Why not both?

Comment: do you have an autokey for "explanation only answers"? because I'd just like to say I hate it when I ask a question and I get back a paragraph of text that doesn't actually tell me how to do something. Usually it tells me something I already knew, maybe from google, but couldn't get the API sorted.

Comment: @xenoterracide: I don't, because that's not something anyone can detect automatically. Many explanation-only answers are perfectly reasonable, and the ones that aren't can only be discerned by trying them. For that, ordinary downvoting and commenting is what you need, I think.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion - a "good answer" is one that will assist future users of the site as well as the current supplicant.  To this end - a specific solution to a niche problem isn't actually all that helpful.

But suggesting an approach and offering a runnable example of how that approach might work, is.

So might even downvote answers that are just a chunk of code. (Not always - I do tend to give some credit for them being 'right'). But usually will comment to suggest adding an explanation and expansion of what's going on, if it isn't self evident.

But will definitely tend to preferentially upvote the answers that contain:

- explanation of what's going on.
- why that's a good approach to take.
- What things you need to consider.
- some sample code to illustrate the point. (needs to be runnable, doesn't need to solve the whole problem).

Of course, that doesn't *always* apply - some answers can be answered trivially. (Although then they may also be offtopic for typographical error or similar)

**TL;DR** - upvote stuff that teaches, comment suggesting that would improve the answer if it's not there.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that I care to take it upon myself to police how others learn, or if they ought to. Additionally, I don't think it's anyone's duty to answer a question just because they know the answer.

I think it's expected only that your answers both: answer the question in a way that you are comfortable with; answer the question **as it was asked.**

If users are asking questions like,

> How would I *implement* a `[ function | class | algorithm ]` that does `XYZ` in `thisLanguage`?

a sensible answer to me would be a *solution*. If you do not believe in handing out code, then by all means, don't answer it, or just offer a nudge in the right direction. Just don't be shocked if the answer with working code, comments, and links to documentation get picked over yours.

**Highly specific inquiries tend to yield highly specified results, and the results' burden of quality rests more on the askers, IMO.**

This is from a long time of observing SO. But what do I know with my 20 rep? =D

Answer (score 5):

Of course this is depending on the specific question but I think the best (in most cases) is to provide a **minimal but self-contained** working example.

That is, it should be possible to just copy the code and run it. (I find it, for example, very annoying when I get a code snipped where I first have to figure out the necessary imports/includes myself.)

But it should also be *minimal*, i.e. show the concept of the solution without distracting noise. For more complicated variants one can add a link to some documentation or similar. The user can then take this minimal example, use it and (if needed) extend it themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I like giving the full blown answer. I often look around for questions that are also interesting for me, where I will also learn something. I have two playgrounds open all the time that are just for SO, one for iOS and one for OSX. (I focus on Swift apps)

Sometimes answering the question results in a little tool that goes on Github. Part of the challenge is explaining every part of the final result, to prevent brainless copy pasting. (also if they are really fresh they can't even pull that off)

It helps me to write better code too, since I'm not writing for myself. It has to be clear and simple and preferably modular. These are things I often ignore when I know no one else will ever look at/use the code I write.

People with some experience won't mind the full blown code, they know how to get the piece they need out of it. Beginners that are on the right track need the extra explaining, but I don't mind doing that.

On the other hand, trying to explain anything to someone who clearly decided to learn how to write code 5 minutes ago is impossible and annoying. No matter how much code you decide to put in your answer they will come back and say it doesn't work because they did something else completely wrong. So I don't think we should base restrictions on answers on people who are in a stage that only lasts a couple of days/weeks.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's all depends on what kinda user who ask those questions.

We've all been a beginner in programming before. Com'on, we did feel helpless at one point, rite ? When we first learn how to code, we don't really care what's happening behind the scene (e.g. data structure/design) and just wanna get things done. I remember it's already a hand full dealing with the program logic on it's own. Asking a person who didn't even get the fundamental/concept right to start thinking the "why"  is a bit asking too much. Let them copy and paste a runnable code to show them how things should be done would at least providing them the correct way to tackle the same problem over and over again.

For intermediate programmer, you can start explaining the concept behind or the weighing between different approach by fewer words without example. You just need to show them the right way to go.

I suggested this simply becoz I strongly believe users with awesome reputation can distinguish whether it's a beginner level programmer or an intermediate one just by looking at the questions.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is the core of your question:

> . . . it seems the chances of new users really learning anything diminishes on full blown code they can hardly even decipher that they might be just copying and pasting.

I agree that full-blown code won't help a new user. I contend that a minimal viable product/snippet is valuable, especially for questions where the problem is that the OP **doesn't know what they don't know** and has reached the end of what can be done without that information.

*Caveat -- If the question is so broad that you cannot answer without giving a full implementation that they can copy-paste-forget, then perhaps you should flag it, not answer?*

I can give you an example using a question+answer I found useful. I think it's especially relevant precisely because several users flagged it (in less than 2 hours) as not **demonstrating a minimal understanding**, which I believe solidifies the OP as a 'new user'.

Let's look at some parts of the question:
[How to highlight a single word in a JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341719/how-to-highlight-a-single-word-in-a-jtextarea)

> I am able to read in the text and give it back to the user, but I cant figure out how to highlight a single word.

OP can get the indices required to highlight but they're still stuck. The missing knowledge here is that the Highlighter class exists and that a JTextArea has an instance of Highlighter which can be easily accessed.

OP asks for the missing information:

> How can I highlight a single word in a JTextArea using java swing?

The only answer was one line of text and then a code snippet that showed getting the Highlighter and using it.

> Use the DefaultHighlighter that comes with your JTextArea. For e.g.,

```
some code
```

This is perfect. The answer addresses the first problem (OP doesn't know the Highlighter class exists) and then addresses the next problem (OP doesn't know how to get an instance of the Highlighter.)

I recognize that using a closed, old, and off-topic question to support my point will irk some of you. Sorry, but it's been a very helpful answer for me, and it's even **still open** in my browser, since I'm working on my own highlighting problem and don't want to lose that initial reference.

Comment: It's not still open in my browser.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's necessary to babysit the intention and morality of someone else.  We can't know if they're going to cut and paste, or instead be delighted at enough detailed code to figure it out for themselves.  There's a certain amount of trust that can be afforded to others until and unless they actually show reason not to trust them.

So a counterpoint to trying to prevent cuts and pastes, is that it expends time on that, while avoiding time focused on simply helping others as best as possible, and letting them decide how much to work in their own best interest.

When TAing in college, I caught those who cheated when I could, but mostly I focused on teaching those who wanted to learn.  I knew well, that those who cheated would not learn as much and would live to regret their lack of skills later... and their lack of self-confidence that comes from not having solved something.

So as a newbie to SO, I've found code answers to be very helpful and more so than a minimalist approach that's trying not to help me "too much."  It's confusing enough, and code often explains better than words what's needed.

To add to that -- I'm a former programmer, so often I can't figure out what's being explained in words, but can figure out code.  Or I can't figure out code but every time I've asked, someone's explained more and I've been very well helped.  (I wish there was a way to select more than one answer, or to select partial helpful answers when it's been a collective response that's gotten me where I'm going.)

The points system in SO works to motivate.  It can also then tend to led to a sense of monitoring others and babysitting that's maybe not necessary or  doesn't lead to adult trust that tends to spark more mature peoples' sticking around.  So that's another angle to assess from.  There's a balance to consider of how to approach everything.